# HTML Form cannot POST to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express

Making a form in HTML where user input data and hit submit. Throws an error when the `submitted.html` file should load.

> Cannot POST /api/submitted

The HTML on my `index.html` file is as follows:

```
<form action="/api/submitted" method="POST">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required><br>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone #" required><br>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                In which campus are you interested?<br>
                <select name="campus" id="" required>
                    <!-- options -->
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="Towson">Towson</option>
                    <option value="Dundalk">Dundalk</option>
                    <option value="ChevyChase">Chevy Chase</option>
                    <option value="SilverSpring">Silver Spring</option>
                </select><br>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                About which workshop would you like to learn more?<br>
                <input type="text" name="request" id="request"><br>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                By submitting your information below, you agree to our 
                <a href="" id="link">Terms of Use</a> 
                and 
                <a href="" id="link">Privacy Policy</a><br>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And then my `submitted.html` text is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <style type="text/css">@import url("css/submitted.css");</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Submitted Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Thank you for your interest in our workshops! A member of our team will reach out soon!
    </header><br><br>
    <p>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">Exit</a><br><br>
        <a href="index.html">Return to form.</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript is as follows:

```
app.post('/api/submitted', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('You posted from a form!');
    console.log(req.body);

    const data = { ...req.body, dateOfApplication: new Date() }; // ... copies whatever i have in an array and makes a deep copy

    const collection = client.db("applications").collection("applicants");
    try {
        await collection.insertOne(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    res.status(201);
    res.redirect('/submitted.html');
});
```

I am trying to get the input data stored onto a MongoDB server, and then that data can be viewed on a separate HTML file. Of course, the data is not being stored, too.

Comment: Can we have the error??

Comment: @Salketer — It's quoted in the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: Assuming `app` in `app.post('/api/submitted'` is the express app and isn't a separate route, I can't see anyway that this code would cause that problem. Did you forget to restart the server after adding that route (so you're still running old code that doesn't support that route)? If not, you need to more provide a more complete [mcve] (althrough you should be able to cut out a bunch of HTML and database logic, reduce it to the bare minimum needed to accept the POST request and serve the form).

Comment: @Quentin, there is more than just "Cannot POST /api/submitted" this cannot be the full info. There may be logs on the server side, the network could at least give an HTTP status code. Troubleshooting will be very different between 404 and 500

Comment: If the server were to throw an exception, then the it would report the error message in the browser. "Cannot POST /api/submitted" is express' standard 404 error message.

Answer (score -1):

try to change form action to full end point api to be like this

```
http://localhost/api/submitted
```

the action you entered is a relative path the will redirect to

```
your_index_directory/api/submitted
```

try to use absolute path of full url as i mentioned before

Comment: The error message (Cannot POST /api/submitted) includes the *full path* so the request is being made to `/api/submitted` and not to `your_index_directory/api/submitted`.